# Parse Int and String into parameter of onclick function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, parameters, onclick

I wanted to parse 1 int and 1 string as param of onclick function.

I've tried below ex:

```
onclick="showModeleditDesi(' . $designation->getDegId().','. (string) $designation->getDegName().')"

onclick="showModeleditDesi(' . $designation->getDegId().',\""+$designation->getDegName()+"\")"
```

and also

```
onclick="showModeleditDesi(' . $designation->getDegId().','/'. $designation->getDegName()  . '/')"
```

When I'm using this script

```
onclick="showModeleditDesi(' . $designation->getDegId().','.$designation->getDegName().')"
```

[image]

It says **Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argunt list**

I google it and searched many answers like this : 
[with the editable, click here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kmv28/44/)

Any references?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$designation->getDegId() , this is not javascript code , i think this is php code , if you use Laravel , you can use blade {{ }} , and also why u set single quotation ?

in javascript every thing put between quotation be a String
you must scape quotation for php , because your code compile first with php parser and then javascript run code , you can check your code in browser source code and see in first parameter has any single quotation

show me your source code after compiling in php , i help you

Comment: Yeah I'm using PHP and I'm set this button manually in PHP. I pass the values from PHP code. But I'm not using Laravel or any kind of framework. I've updated my question. Please check

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
onclick="showModeleditDesi(' . $designation->getDegId().',\''.$designation->getDegName().'\')"
```

Thank your time.